# get column position (like first, second, etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

when I click on an icon, it will change but I want to know in which column is clicked icon (like the first one or the second one  or the third one, etc.)

```js
$(".fa-caret-down").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(".fa-caret-down")){
        $(this).removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-up");
        //console.log() - in which column it was changed
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass("fa-caret-up").addClass("fa-caret-down");
        //console.log() - in which column it was changed
    }
});
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>Name<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>Price<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>1h %<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>24h %<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>Timestamp<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2 align" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery index function will return the index of the element.

```js
$(".fa-caret-down").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().index()) //- in which column it was changed
    if($(this).is(".fa-caret-down")){
        $(this).removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-up");
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass("fa-caret-up").addClass("fa-caret-down");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>Name<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>Price<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>1h %<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>24h %<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
            <th>Timestamp<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2 align" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Separately (not worth a separate answer), I tend to add details to the column, eg `<th data-col="name">` then `$(this).closest("th").data("col")`.  Then the position of the column won't matter and you can move the columns without rewriting your js.

Comment: @freedomn-m Good idea, also if we add a unique `class` to all `th`'s will return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

simply use event delegation and `classList.replace()` method
(and it is more  clear with css)

Each `TD` or `TH` element have a `cellIndex` property

```js
document.querySelector('table thead').onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('i.fas')) return   // ignore clicks from elsewhere

  let eTH    = e.target.closest('th')
    , onDown = e.target.classList.contains('fa-caret-down')
    ;
  console.clear()
  console.log( 'column :', eTH.cellIndex, eTH.innerText, onDown?'UP':'DOWN'  ),
  setTimeout(console.clear,3000)

  if (onDown) e.target.classList.replace('fa-caret-down','fa-caret-up')
  else        e.target.classList.replace('fa-caret-up','fa-caret-down')
  }
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table thead th i.fas {
  cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" >

<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>Name<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>Price<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>1h %<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>24h %<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>Timestamp<i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2 align" ></i></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

> but IMHO it would be cooler if the whole column header is used to invert the graph

```js
document.querySelector('table thead').onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('table thead th, table thead th i.fas')) return  // ignore clicks from elsewhere

  let eIfas  = target.querySelector('i.fas')
    , eTH    = target.closest('th')
    , onDown = eIfas.classList.contains('fa-caret-down')
    ;
  console.clear()
  console.log( 'column :', eTH.cellIndex, ':',eTH.innerText, onDown?'UP':'DOWN'  )
  setTimeout(console.clear,5000)

  if (onDown)  eIfas.classList.replace('fa-caret-down','fa-caret-up')
  else         eIfas.classList.replace('fa-caret-up','fa-caret-down')
  }
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table thead th {
  cursor : pointer;
}
table thead th:hover {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
table thead th:hover i.fas {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" >

<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th># <i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>Name <i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>Price <i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>1h % <i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>24h % <i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2" ></i></th>
      <th>Timestamp <i class="fas fa-caret-down ml-2 align" ></i></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain javascript to get it, let me show below:

```
$(".fa-caret-down").click(function(event){
    console.log(event.target.parentElement.cellIndex)
    if($(this).is(".fa-caret-down")){
        $(this).removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-up");
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass("fa-caret-up").addClass("fa-caret-down");
    }
});
```

1. Pass the event as parameter into click function:
2. Using this element get the current element using `target`, aftet get its parent node using `parentElement` because the event is triggered clicking on `<i><i/>` element and it's inside a `th`, and finally get the cell index using `cellIndex`
3. You don't need a console.log inside if and else, you need only  when the event id triggered